# Keeping the in-browser search box active in Google Chrome

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, search

In Firefox, if I press <kbd>/</kbd>, I can get the in-browser (on-the-same-page) search box to pop up at the bottom temporarily (it will time-out after some short period).

[image: quick find in firefox]

However, if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>, it will stay up, and if I click to a new page, it will re-perform the on-page search, updating the count of found instances.

[image: normal firefox find]

In Google Chrome, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd> yields the on-page search box for that page only, and as soon as a link is clicked, it disappears.

[image: chrome search box]

I know that on the next page I can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd> (or <kbd>F3</kbd> to 'Find Next', but would like to find a way to mimic Firefox's functionality in this aspect.

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Best thing that I have been able to find (in my short search) is [chrome-type-ahead](http://code.google.com/p/chrome-type-ahead/).

> [Type-ahead-find](http://www.mozilla.org/access/type-ahead/) (or find as you type) is an extremely useful
>   accessibility feature (a core functionality in major browsers like
>   Firefox or Safari), but it's not implemented in Chrome ([nor planned to
>   be](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=150)). So -unless Chromium developers come to their senses- we will have
>   to resign ourselves to use an extension.